# How to migrate Hibernate @Audited informarion from table field?

Tags: java, hibernate, audit, hibernate-annotations, auditing

I need to change my database structure that way: move one field from @Audited entity to another @Audited entity with no loss of audit information. How can I migrate it?

1. By liquibase migration I create new field in table T1 and T1_aud
2. Update T1 with values of old table field T2
3. **Somehow migrate audit to T1**
4. Drop column from T2 and T2_aud

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just adding the same values to AUD table solves the problem.